# InternalError: too much recursion on large polygon insertion

Tags: mongodb, recursion, insert, geospatial

I've got geoJSON file containing a set of neighbourhoods with their respective geometry and want to add it to my mongoDB collection.
The problem is that the polygons contain too many points.
This is one of them (Pasted in a link because its too large):

http://hastebin.com/ukekekayad.pl

2 of 3 times I get the error **InternalError: too much recursion**
How can I prevent this from happening? I can't reduce the amount of points in an automated way as the polygon could lose its proper shape.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What code is doing the recursion?  Adding a polygon to a data base isn't a naturally recursive algorithm, so I'm hoping that you control the source code.

Comment: The code is too large to include in stackflow, I added it to that link.
I know the its not a naturaly recursive algorithm, but the error its still poping randomly. The worst of all is that sometime the insert works fine. You can try it yourself with large points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDb probably index the points somehow whilst the insertion, don't really know whats the limit.

Alternative solution is simplifying the coordinates with the following tool.

http://www.mapshaper.org/